# UnsopportedOperationException TODO when running R script with renjin in java

Tags: java, r, renjin

I'm new to R and Renjin, but I'm trying to run a legacy R script from a spring boot service and I'm getting this Unsupported exception. I've narrowed down the issue on the legacy script to a call made to svymean R function. 
I've added details in here https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/494

The design is generated with:

```
svrepdesign(data = svy_data, type = "JK1", weights = ~ weights, repweights = "weights[1-9]+")
```

What I've tried so far is:

- Adding dependencies that could have been missing (matrix, base, stats), this didn't work and in some cases it only generated more problems
- Commenting the parameters I'm passing in one by one, this didn't make any difference, the error still appears
- I also tried with another similar function svytotal and I'm getting the same error

Could it be that it's just not supported to calculate the mean with replicated weighted? And if so, there is another way to calculate this and still use renjin? And if not, any other recommendation to use instead of renjin to run R legacy code?

The same script with the same parameters is running just fine from within RStudio.